# When a long integer is cast into a short one, what happened?

Tags: java, casting

I use java to copy one long integer y to a short integer x:

```
long y = 40002;
short x = (short) y;
System.out.println("x now equals " + x);
```

The result is: x now equals -25534.

I tried to figure out how 40002 was cast into -25534, but I failed. The 40002 corresponds to 1001 1100 0100 0010, the -25534 corresponds to 1110 0011 1011 1110. Can any friend tell me what happened in this process? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `2^16` - `40002` = `25534` :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you have done by casting a `long` to a `short` is a *narrowing primitive conversion*, which is covered by the [JLS, Section 5.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3):

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause the sign of the resulting value to differ from the sign of the input value.

The `long` value `40002` is the following 64 bits:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 10011100 01000010
```

The conversion only retains the least significant 16 bits:

```
10011100 01000010
```

That leading `1` is interpreted in 2's complement notation to be -2^15, not +2^15.  That explains why there is a difference of 2^16, of 65,536, in the `long` value and the `short` value.

Comment: I like this as a complement to my answer.

Comment: @MattBall I like it *instead of* your answer. Yours describes a lot of subtractions and additions that don't actually happen. This describes  what actually happens.

Answer (score 4):

[Integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) happened.

A short is two signed bytes, which means that `Short.MAX_VALUE` is 2<sup>15</sup>-1, which is 32,767. "Larger" values logically "wrap around" into the negative range.

In this case the excess amount is 40,002 - 2<sup>15</sup> = 7234
`Short.MIN_VALUE` is -2<sup>15</sup> = -32,768
-32,768 + 7234 = -25,534

which is the number you're wondering about.

Comment: I see..  40,002 - 32,767 = 7,235 + -32,768 = -25,533..  don't know where that extra 1 went..

Comment: @Woodrow it's 40,002 - 32,76**8**

Answer (score 0):

Thank all of you guys. According to all of your answers, I summarize as follows:
The long value 40002 is the following 64 bits:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 10011100 01000010
```

The conversion only retains the least significant 16 bits:

```
10011100 01000010
```

When JVM regard 10011100 01000010 as a short integer, it will compute it like this:

```
-2^15 + 00011100 01000010 = -32768 + 7234 = -25534
```

This is it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it's going to cycle through the values, when you reach the max and add 1 it's going to be the lowest value, so 32768 is going to be -32768, when you reach 65536 (32768*2) it's going to be 0 and when you reach 98303 (32768*2+32767) it's going to be 32767, if you add one you'll get to 98304 (32768*3) and it's going to be -32768 again.

So 40002 (which is higher than 32768 but lower than 32768*2) is clearly going to be a negative number when converted to short.